# Capitalization of the first letter of each word in java using substring lower and upper methods only

Tags: java, string, loops

I have an assignment at school and it is to capitalize the first letter of each word of a string given by the user. We are restricted to use only `substring()` `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` methods. I wrote a code myself and it has some logical error. Can anyone please help me out. Appreciated.

```
String a=jTextField1.getText();
int x=a.length();
a=a.toLowerCase();
String b=a.substring(0,1);
String c=a.substring(1,x);
b=b.toUpperCase();
a=b+c;
String g="";
    for (int i=0;i<=x;i=i+1){
       if (a.charAt(i)==' '){
         String d=a.substring(0,i);
         String e=a.substring(i+1,1);
         String f=a.substring(i+2);
         e=e.toUpperCase();
         g=d+e+f;
       }
    }
System.out.println(g);
```

Comment: *and it has some logical error* can you explain it in detail

Comment: As for the logical error, it says "String index out of range: -5" for eg when i give a string "ayush is my name" as the input

Comment: Perhaps you can post the entire stack trace. This will give us and you a clue where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `substring` function is defined as: `public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

And in this line you pass 1 as the ending index:

```
String e=a.substring(i+1,1);
```

This will throw an error because the starting index is more than the ending index (Except when `i` is equal to 0. And when it is 0 it will be returning an empty `String`)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are Zero based, so the last index is x-1

```
for (int i=0;i<x;i=i+1){
```

Also normaly `i=i+1` is written as `i++`

Comment: I tried 'step into' to debug my program and it seems that the loop only executes the number of times equal to that of the index number of the first blank.